# visitor_id null in report_viewed_product_index magento2

Tags: recently-viewed

when visitor_id  is null then recently viewed product not showing on frontend.
why visitor_id  saving 'null' in table?
[image]

Comment: Have got this solution?

Comment: yes! i found another solution for that

Comment: How can we manage it?

Comment: Create recently view Widgets from admin and write some code on product view page for design. create for maincontener

Comment: if need help ping on skype.

Comment: Actually, I am using Amasty Automatic Related Products Extension in which I am not getting visitor_idfrom this table.